# Home page not displayed in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I am getting below error when developing first web app in STS in Spring Boot (v1.2.3.RELEASE) while opening this url (http://localhost:8080/riyan/):

**Error:**

*This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Jun 05 23:08:55 PKT 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available*

**Application.properties**

```
logging.config = ${app.root.dir}/config/logback.xml
spring.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix = .jsp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:${app.root.dir}/data/accounts;crypt_key=901a6105813eb65326bf35790a965432;crypt_type=blowfish;hsqldb.write_delay=false;create=false;sql.syntax_ora=true

spring.datasource.username=accounts
spring.datasource.password=accounts
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.datasource-internal.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package com.riyan.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController 
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String getHomePage() {
        return "login";
    }

}
```

**JSP:**

login.jsp is present at WEB-INF->views->login.jsp

Followings are contents from pivotal server console:

**Console Output:**

```
23:08:47.239 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext

23:08:47.989 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5596ab: startup date [Fri Jun 05 23:08:32 PKT 2015]; root of context hierarchy

23:08:48.333 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

23:08:48.333 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/error],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[text/html],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

23:08:48.427 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

23:08:48.427 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]

23:08:48.614 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
```

Please let me know if anything further is required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your config that is setting the server context to "/riyan". You should add this to your application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/riyan
```

Otherwise you will probably find your actual login.jps is at
http://localhost:8080/